# git rebase fails - ends up deleting file

Tags: git, azure-devops, rebase

I some times experience something strange when trying to rebase. The rebase fails, and one of my changed files ends up being marked as deleted.

Can someone help me understand what's going on?

Here's the most resent incident:

I have done a couple of local commits to a new feature branch:

```
C:\source\project [remove-index-html-from-urls]> git ll
97d1af8 (HEAD, remove-index-html-from-urls) Removed unused code [Vegar Vikan]
18      31      WebApiRole/Controllers/HomeController.cs

6115cd1 Do not redirect to index.html - just serve. [Vegar Vikan]
2       14      WebApiRole/Controllers/HomeController.cs
2       2       WebApiRole/app/app.js

586f67a (master) Merge branch 'unique-requestid-for-logging' [Vegar Vikan]
```

I then fetch master...

```
C:\source\Webrapportering-Git [remove-index-html-from-urls]> git fetch origin master
remote: Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From https://finale.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Finale
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   af56971..b4bb100  master     -> origin/master
```

...before I initiate the rebase:

```
C:\source\Webrapportering-Git [remove-index-html-from-urls]> git rebase origin/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Do not redirect to index.html - just serve.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
<stdin>:29: trailing whitespace.
             */
<stdin>:45: trailing whitespace.
        });
warning: 2 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        WebApiRole/Controllers/HomeController.cs
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Do not redirect to index.html - just serve.
The copy of the patch that failed is found in:
   c:/source/Webrapportering-Git/.git/rebase-apply/patch

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".

C:\source\Webrapportering-Git [(b4bb100...)|REBASE +0 ~1 -1]> git status
```

And here you can see that things have gone 'boink'.

```
C:\source\Webrapportering-Git [(b4bb100...)|REBASE +0 ~1 -1]> git status
rebase in progress; onto b4bb100
You are currently rebasing branch 'remove-index-html-from-urls' on 'b4bb100'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   WebApiRole/Controllers/HomeController.cs
        deleted:    WebApiRole/app/app.js

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

As you can see, some how git decides that one of my files is deleted. Why?
The patch file that it tried to apply does not mention any delete?

The conflict that it mentions, the local changes that will be overwritten, is also a mystery, case my repo is clean before the rebase.

Any clues?

(Aborting the rebase and starting over usually do the trick)

Comment: What's the output of `git log HEAD..origin/master` ?  Perhaps one of those incoming commits deleted app.js.

Comment: no, there are no such commits anywhere. `git log HEAD...` gives no output.

Comment: That doesn't seem right. From the output you posted there's at least one commit b4bb100 that's in origin/master but not in remove-index-html-from-urls. How about `git log 97d1af8..b4bb100` ?

Comment: I guess it didn't return anything since I restarted the rebase and it succeeded? `git log 97d1af8..b4bb100` returns a whole lot of commits. No that deletes app.js.

Comment: When you `git rebase --abort` and try again, do you sometimes experience a slightly different rebase behaviour? ie, slightly different changes each time, or is it always the same?

Comment: I believe it's the same.

Comment: @Vegar I think my colleague and I have been experiencing this odd behaviour with VSTS this week too.

Comment: This is locally using git cli.